# How can I get a process's stdin by a process id?

Tags: python, linux

I know i can get process's `stdin` use subprocess in `python` like:

```
import subprocess
f = subprocess.Popen('python example.py',stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
f.stdin.write('some thing')
```

but I want only know the  pid which i want to write to the process's `stdin`
how can i do this?

Comment: You want to hijack another process's stdin? That's not a very nice thing to do...

Comment: yes,i want to write someting to a other process's stdin

Comment: on what machine do you want it?

Comment: I'm glad this question got an answer that helped before it was closed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply write to `/proc/PID/fd/1`:

```
import os.path
pid = os.getpid() # Replace your PID here - writing to your own process is boring
with open(os.path.join('/proc', str(pid), 'fd', '1'), 'a') as stdin:
  stdin.write('Hello there\n')
```