# How to create a resource with Resource id?

Tags: php, proc-open, resource-id

When I used `proc_open`, it returns a resource handle represented as `Resource id #4`. This code runs on the server, and I want to use this 'handle' again using the id. But after some kind of data transfer between the client and the server, all I got is the resource's id, `Resource id #4`, instead of the pointer.

Is is possible to recreate the resource with the only id?

Answer (score 1):

No, this could never reliably work, because in a new request you have no clue whether the resource is even still accessible - in a preforked environment like Apache the second request might be executed by a completely different process, in which accessing the same resource would be impossible on the OS level. Also, in a clustered and/or load balanced environment the second request could even end up on a completely different server.

Comment: But the process created by `proc_open` should not be closed until I use `proc_close`, thus the process is still running. So is it possible to use the process or create a new handle of it when accessible to its process id?

Comment: As said, there is probably not even be a relation to the process in question in a regular hosting situation - Apache preforks 10 childs at least in a normal situation, that makes a 10% chance this could work at best. You could use [proc_get_status](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-get-status.php) to retrieve the PID for the process, and do some stuff with that later on with shell based commands, but that's the best you can get.

Comment: That's too bad. Can the resource just be stored somewhere in the memory of the server? When the request comes, I just use the resource stored?

Comment: A `Resource` is just something local to the running PHP instance. If you want to store something that'll remain valid on the server for a while, use the `PID` as suggested above.

Comment: I see. I will try some shell based commands on the process. It will be quite complicated since I want to use `STDIN` to input a string to the program the process is running and retrieve the result from `STDOUT`

Comment: One more question please.. How can I get the `STDIN` and `STDOUT` of a process using its `PID`?

Comment: Keep in mind that it's very bad practice to do so, but [here's a workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312764/how-can-i-get-a-processs-stdin-by-a-process-id).

Comment: I know it's bad. Here is the thing. I'm writing a online coding website and users can compile and run his code on the server. In order to allow the user to use sentences like `scanf("%d",&a)`, the server should be able to interact with the user. I used `proc_open` to do so so the process created can be maintained.. Is there a better way?

Comment: I think the proper solution would be to write your own daemon that spawns and manages the processes, and then communicate with that daemon from PHP through sockets or pipes. I think it's the only clean and proper solution.